# Create a folder with models,views and urls inside an app.How to import these models in the main app model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created an App using the startapp command and inside that i have created other files.But when i try to import that model in the init file of main app it get this as an error::
from subapp1.models.models import TodoList
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subapp1'

How can i import this?
I am written this in the main app init file-->>

from subapp1.models.models import TodoList

**all** = ['TodoList',]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your app in the settings file ? like this ?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'name_of_your_app',
```

]

Comment: Yeah I have added that in setting.py .I got the solution.My import was wrong.It should be like this
MainApp.subapp1.models.models import TodoList 
with this migration worked .

Comment: Glad you found it.